# VBA Public Array : how to?

Tags: arrays, vba

So today's problem is getting me mad because that should be easy and i can not find the answer :

How to declare a public array in VBA ? I'm using an array with the letters A, B, C,... because i'm working with Excel cells, and i don't want to declare it in every function i create, right ?
I've tried to look on the web first and i read that you have to declare it in a different module, so that's what i've done :

```
Public colHeader As String
colHeader = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
```

But Visual Basic doesn't like it...

So what shall i do ?

Thank's a lot :)

Edit : the problem is more about asigning values to the array than to declare it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Declare array as global across subs in a application:

```
Public GlobalArray(10) as String
GlobalArray = Array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L')

Sub DisplayArray()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 to UBound(GlobalArray, 1)
        MsgBox GlobalArray(i)

    Next i
End Sub
```

Method 2: Pass an array to sub. Use ParamArray.

```
Sub DisplayArray(Name As String, ParamArray Arr() As Variant)
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr())
        MsgBox Name & ": " & Arr(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```

ParamArray must be the last parameter.

Comment: First line of example 1 gives a very annoying compile error in Access 2007.

Comment: I copied the very same code to VBA to test it out. When doing so I receive a compilation error. While highlighting the "A" in the array to be assigned it says that this is not allowed outside of a procedure. Any hints?

Comment: Yes, I don't know why this answer is the most upvoted as it is wrong. You cannot modify an array outside of a sub. As other answers point out, you should create a sub that modifies it, or modify it with `Workbook_Open()` or the like

Comment: First 2 lines give following problem (because of single quote ' I think):
Erreur de compilation  (Compilation error)
Attendu : Expression  (Waiting for : Expression)
Changing to double quotes give a compilation error when lauching the code : 
Instruction incorrecte à l'extérieur d'une procédure. (Incorrect instruction outside of a procedure)

Answer (score 10):

You are using the wrong type. The `Array(...)` function returns a `Variant`, not a `String`.

Thus, in the Declaration section of your module (it does not need to be a different module!), you define

```
Public colHeader As Variant
```

and somewhere at the beginning of your program code (for example, in the `Workbook_Open` event) you initialize it with

```
colHeader = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
```

Another (simple) alternative would be to create a function that returns the array, e.g. something like

```
Public Function GetHeaders() As Variant
    GetHeaders = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
End Function
```

This has the advantage that you do not need to initialize the global variable and the drawback that the array is created again on every function call.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit

Public colHeader

Sub test()

    ReDim colHeader(11)
    colHeader = Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
End Sub

Sub verify_test()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = LBound(colHeader) To UBound(colHeader)
        MsgBox "colHeader( " & i & " ) = " & colHeader(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Dim colHeader(12)
colHeader = ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
```

Unfortunately the code found online was VB.NET not VBA.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, seems to work as global :

```
Dim savePos(2 To 8) As Integer
```

And **can** call it from every sub, for example getting first element :

```
MsgBox (savePos(2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
     Public myarray (1 To 10)
     Public Count As Integer
     myarray(1) = "A"
     myarray(2) = "B"
     myarray(3) = "C"
     myarray(4) = "D"
     myarray(5) = "E"
     myarray(6) = "F"
     myarray(7) = "G"
     myarray(8) = "H"
     myarray(9) = "I"
     myarray(10) = "J"
Private Function unwrapArray()
     For Count = 1 to UBound(myarray)
       MsgBox "Letters of the Alphabet : " & myarray(Count)
     Next 
End Function
```

Comment: This won't work - you cannot modify array elements outside of a function or sub. You would get a compile error on line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically what I found is that you can declare the array, but when you set it vba shows you an error.

So I put an special sub to declare global variables and arrays, something like:

```
Global example(10) As Variant

Sub set_values()

example(1) = 1
example(2) = 1
example(3) = 1
example(4) = 1
example(5) = 1
example(6) = 1
example(7) = 1
example(8) = 1
example(9) = 1
example(10) = 1

End Sub
```

And whenever I want to use the array, I call the sub first, just in case

```
call set_values

Msgbox example(5)
```

Perhaps is not the most correct way, but I hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

What actually worked for me was to declare a public function (anywhere, really):

```
Public Function return_colheaders() As Variant
    Dim colheader
    colheader= Array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L")
    return_colheaders= colheader
End Function
```