# VBA Define a simple static public array

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to accomplish this obviously simple thing, but somehow VBA keeps serving me weird errors.
I would like to have a global array named styles containing the following strings: Settings, Titles, Comment and Direct Copy.
in Code:

```
Public styles(4) As String
```

Directly assigning the array was not working for me so i did this via a sub:

```
sub Populate()
  styles(0) = "Settings"
  styles(1) = "Titles"
  styles(2) = "Comment"
  styles(3) = "Direct Copy"
  Debug.Print styles
End Sub
```

However this does not work as it gives a compile error: Type mismatch on the debug.print line... The expected result was something like:
("Settings", "Titles", ..) etc like any programming language would return.

So how do I get a public array containing strings in VBA Excel such that I can use them in the same module across functions and subs?

Comment: Try `Debug.Print styles(0)...Debug.Print styles(1)....Debug.Print styles(2)....Debug.Print styles(3).....`

Comment: this answer is not working for me, it does look elegant:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654281/vba-public-array-how-to

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this form of public declaration and array element assignment.

```
Option Explicit

Public styles As Variant

Sub printStyles()

    styles = Array("Settings", "Titles", "Comment", "Direct Copy")

    Debug.Print LBound(styles) & "to" & UBound(styles)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(styles) To UBound(styles)
        Debug.Print styles(i)
    Next i

    Debug.Print Join(styles, ", ")

End Sub
```

BTW, there a reserved [Styles Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/styles-object-excel) which you may have difficulty using if you continue to use reserved words as the names of your public and private variables.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the extra explanatory code!

Answer (score 2):

This is how to print the array (twice):

```
Public styles(4) As String

Sub Populate()
    styles(0) = "Settings"
    styles(1) = "Titles"
    styles(2) = "Comment"
    styles(3) = "Direct Copy"

    '1. print is here ---v
    Dim cnt As Long
    For cnt = LBound(styles) To UBound(styles)
        Debug.Print styles(cnt)
    Next cnt
    '--------------------^        
    '2. print is here ---v
    Debug.Print Join(styles, vbCrLf)
    '--------------------^
End Sub
```

This is what you get (twice):

```
Settings
Titles
Comment
Direct Copy
```

The first time you loop by the elements and print each of them on a new line.
The second time you return a string created by joining a number of substrings contained in the array.

[Join MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/join-function)

Comment: Is there a way to declare a public array like you would do in python or java like:
array = ("value1", "value2", etc..)

Comment: The ultimate goal of the array is to verify styles of an excel and if they are in an array they need to be written to a txt file

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje - `Dim Styles as Variant : Styles = Array("Value1", "Value2", "Value3")`

Comment: if I do it like that I get the following compile error:
Invalid outside procedure
code: 
Public styles As Variant: styles = Array("Settings", "Titles", "Comment", "Direct Copy")

Comment: I don't know if the OP was ever expecting a fifth array element but styles(4) leaves 5 elements for a zero-based array.

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje  - it should be in a procedure (within a Sub or Function).

Comment: @Vityata, placing the following in a sub: styles = Array("Settings", "Titles", "Comment", "Direct Copy") still results in a compile error: can't assign to array

Comment: @Brilsmurfffje - this is because you do not have `Dim Styles As Variant` within the sub, but you are using the `Public styles(4) As String` outside the sub. Write `Public styles As Variant` outside or `Dim Styles As Variant` within.