# Can I change the column showing in the same report through a button?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a report that opens from like 7 different forms, and I wanted it to show a bit different from each one (not by much, just 1 column).

Is there a way that the report can show different columns from each form or do I have to create the same report 7 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this I would make use of the OpenArgs Property.

Use VBA to pass value through this property to the report. For each different button i would pass a different value Ex. ("ThisLocation", "ThisOtherLocation", "ThisRandomPlace", etc). Then based on the value that is passed in, I would create hidden expression for the columns you don't want to show on "said version";

This solution will create the allusion of 7 different reports, but be One that shows data based upon a value you pass undeneath that the user will never see or have to enter. See below for more information on the OpenArgs Property.

https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/Forms/openargs/index.htm

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Chance Finley's answer, I suggest passing the values in a multidimensional public array. Making it public enables passing the array within multiple userforms.

Each time you want to show different information in the report, you can overwrite it with the information in the array.

Here you can see how a public array is created:
[VBA Public Array : how to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654281/vba-public-array-how-to)

Best regards

Comment: Interesting alternative. Didn't know anything about this.